# Nested for/while loop python triangle

Tags: nested-loops

Code

```
num = int(input(“Enter the number of lines: “))
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(1,i):
    print(num, the end='')
num = num+1
print()
```

I am writing a program which is should be like this.

```
Enter the number of lines: 10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 
38 39 40 41 42 43 44 
45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59
60 61 62
63 64 
65
```

I don’t have any example from the lecturer, i just following the step from website, but the output of my code is like this: i am confused where i made the mistake,  don’t get any clue to wear `for` or `while`. Please help me, thank you.

```
10
11 12 
13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 
38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

Comment: does any of the solution below help? If it does, I recommend you put closure to your question by marking one of the answers as accepted. You can do so by clicking on the check mark beside an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_data = input('Enter number of lines: ')
num = int(input_data)

# how many items to print in the first line?
items_to_print = num

# what's the starting number?
print_number = 11

for i in range(0, num):
    
    # don't decrease num
    # decrease items_to_print
    # each line will reduce 1 item to print
    for j in range(0, items_to_print):

        print(print_number, end = ' ')
        print_number += 1

    print()
    items_to_print -= 1
```

Result:

```
Enter number of lines: 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
38 39 40 41 42 43 44
45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59
60 61 62
63 64
65
```

## Explanation

Start small and make your way up.

First just do this:

```
input_data = input('Enter number of lines: ')
num = int(input_data)
print(num)
```

That'll print 10 if you entered 10. Great.

Second, add the first for loop and test whether it will print 10 rows.

```
input_data = input('Enter number of lines: ')
num = int(input_data)

for i in range(0, num):
    print(f'Printing line {i}')
```

Third, try to print a block of 10 x 10. So, you add another variable called items_to_print. Set it to num. If you enter 10 as input, you will get 10 rows and 10 columns.

```
input_data = input('Enter number of lines: ')
num = int(input_data)

print_number = 0
items_to_print = num

for i in range(0, num):
    print(f'Printing line {i}')

    for j in range(0, items_to_print):
        print(print_number, end = ' ')
```

Fourth step is to reduce the number of zeros printed before restarting the `i` loop. So, you decrement items_to_print.

```
input_data = input('Enter number of lines: ')
num = int(input_data)

print_number = 0
items_to_print = num

for i in range(0, num):
    print(f'Printing line {i}')

    for j in range(0, items_to_print):
        print(print_number, end = ' ')

    items_to_print -= 1
```

Now that your printing is working great, let's set print_number to start with 11 and each time a print happens in `j` loop, increment print_number. Then you will have same code I published at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have three little problems so let's address them one at a time.

First: default range function starts at 0 so when your j starts at one you are missing one iteration of the cicle. That explains missing one column and row but not two so let's keep going.

Second: the range function is non inclusive meaning you're I goes from 0 to 9 then in the inner loop you go from 1 to a maximum of 8. There's your missing second iteration.

Third: you are looping from 1 to an encreasing value what you want is the opposite so you need a decreasing range.

This is how you're code should look like.

```
num = 11
for i in range(10, 0, - 1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(num, end = " ")
        num += 1
    print()
```

Good luck and happy coding